# MPMoviePlayerController fullscreen mode issue

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a problem with my code that plays a video file. Whenever I play the file in fullscreen mode the playback doesn't occupy all of my screen. Here is the relevant code:

```
     NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"Somefile.mov"];
     moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES];
    moviePlayer.view.frame = self.switchView.frame;
    [self.switchView addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)                                                 
    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
    object:moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(playbackStateDidChange:)                                                 
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
     object:moviePlayer];

    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [moviePlayer play];
```

Here is the output I get:

[image]

Comment: try this one rather then the frame you are setting moviePlayer.view.frame = self.switchView.bounds;

Comment: It seems that the lower bar is in the right position now, but the top bar is still lower. http://img849.imageshack.us/i/defaultj.png/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Option A: Use the `MPMovieViewController` instead and display it modally using `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:`.

Option B: Make sure your switchView (which you use for adding the moviePlayer's view to) actually occupies the entire screen.

Option C: Readjust the frame of the moviePlayer's view with negative vertical offsets until it fits - eg.: `moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, -20.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f);`

Note: MPMoviePlayerController **always** displays a status bar when using the control style `MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen`, no matter how the rest of your app handles the status-bar.

Comment: I did Option C and it solved my problem. In addition in viewDidAppear i put moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, -20.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f); because otherwise the movie screen jumps! But for the addSubView part i lieave it on 0.0f.

Answer (score 0):

Change the controlstyle property of your player from the method below:           -(void)applyUserSettingsToMoviePlayer

player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullScreen causes the above problem,change it to MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded and see if that works.