# IOS 6 - Status Bar Not Showing after Playing video

Tags: ios, statusbar

I have an `MPMoviePlayerViewController` in my application and am using that to play videos in fullscreen.

This works fine on IOS 5 OS on iPad.

But on iOS 6 on iPad 3, after playing the video, the status bar disappears and is replaced by a white space.

Is it sloppy to use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:NO];`
to restore the status bar everywhere I have a video?

As my app is very big, can anyone provide an alternate method?

Answer (score 3):

I added an observer to the MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification. In this observer, I create an NSTimer to fire two seconds later. Within the message that the NSTimer fires, I reset the status bar style as well as the status bar. The timer is required because I noticed that the status bar goes into an inconsistent state much after the animations for exiting out of full screen complete.

So in the ViewController which manages the MPMoviePlayer, I do the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidExitFullScreenCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:self.moviePlayerController];
```

Then within the notification selector:

```
- (void) moviePlayerDidExitFullScreenCallback:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(setStatusBarVisible:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}
```

and within the setStatusBarVisible selector:

```
- (void) setStatusBarVisible: (NSTimer *)timer {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this same problem, it seems there is some issue with iOS 6 when using 
`MPMovieControlStyleEmbeded` with `FullScreen = YES`
it may fail to play the video or calling the player twice, which creates some frame positioning issues.

I end up have to change the whole app to use `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated` from the view controller which seems to be a more proper way to play video in this new iOS 6

[MPMoviePlayerController fullscreen mode issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689107/mpmovieplayercontroller-fullscreen-mode-issue)

Comment: Can you pls check this out and find a solution for this issue also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725941/ios-6-issue-with-mpmovieplayercontroller